# How do I update a custom field in a many2many join table?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a table **Experiment** and a table **Task**. I have successfully created a many2many relationship between them:

```
// Experiment represents a set of tasks
type Experiment struct {
    gorm.Model
    Code        string `json:"code" gorm:"not null;"`
    Name        string `json:"name" gorm:"not null;default:''"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"not null;default:''"`
    Tasks       []Task `json:"tasks" gorm:"many2many:experiment_tasks;"`
}

// Task represents a model to store task data
type Task struct {
    gorm.Model
    Title       string `json:"title" gorm:"unique;not null;default:''"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    Route       string `json:"route" gorm:"not null"`
    Type        string `json:"type"`
}


// ExperimentTask is a join table between experiments and tasks
type ExperimentTask struct {
    ExperimentID uint
    TaskID       uint
    Order        int    <--- custom field
}
```

experiment_tasks is automatically created by gorm, but I defined this ExperimentTask struct because I wanted to add an additional *Order* field to the join table.

How do I populate/access the *Order* field?

Comment: Then spit the relation many-to-many to  one-to-many from both table with ExperimentTask

Comment: @NicholasLee did you ever solve this? I'm dealing with the same thing right now.

Comment: Found this answer for future folks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63105661/gorm-associations-many-to-many